# What is the difference between Mono and .NET Framework

Tags: .net, mono

What is the major difference between `Mono` and the `.NET Framework`? Can you easily convert a `.NET` assembly to use the `Mono` framework?

Comment: You can also read the Mono FAQ: http://mono-project.com/FAQ:_General